# B2 visa 181 days divided between two separate stays during 2017 in USA. Is this ok?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

Will spend 181 days in USA during 2017 divided between two separate visits. One lasted Jan 5 - May 11 and the next will be Nov 8 until Dec 31 2017. In total this will be 181 days in the calendar year. Cruising means my arrival will be Nov 8. Will this be ok?

Comment: Will you leave the US on December 31? You will need to convince immigration that you are not trying to live in the US. Stays are not counted per calendar year.

Comment: Will stay until April 15 so second stay will be 159 days in total from Nov to April

Comment: You should be careful about establishing tax residency.

Answer (score 2):

The "total" number of days in a calendar year that you are in the US has no significance. Each admission is separate.

When you next seek entry on B2, you will normally be admitted for 6 months. However, the officer can decide to give you a shorter period of admission or even deny you entry altogether, if he feels like it.

Comment: Days in the US in a calendar year does matter for tax purposes, in that you aquire an obligation to file a tax return if you reach 183. He's not doing that if he sticks to his schedule though.

Comment: If he feels like it? The IO has to refer the passenger to secondary. The chief officer makes the decision to refuse entry. It doesn't happen just because an IO "feels like it!"